# How do ascending neural pathways filter unimportant information?

Tags: brain, neurophysiology, information, brain-stem

In school they told us one of the functions of the ascending neural pathways is to filter unimportant information. But the neural signal I know, is only a chemical-electrical chain of neurons. Is this filtering of unimportant information reminiscent of the gradual attenuation of the signal during the travel from the periphery all the way up to the brain? If so, how does that work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `**the** ascending neural pathway`, do you mean `ascending neural pathway**s**`?

Comment: @Troyseph Definitely, if it's only grammar based note.

Comment: Was more of a distinction between a singularly important `single pathway` or them in general. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neuron cannot know the *importance* of a signal in any applied sense, that is, it can't know the difference between one triggered by a feather or one by a hammer... on an individual basis.

A single neuron can however accumulate information in a number of ways, either by requiring multiple incoming triggers (filtering out localised signals, i.e. from a single connected neuron) or they can require repeated triggers (filtering out weak/freak/accidental signals from a connected neurons). This is called summation: [image: Summation!]

These filtering events occur at the synapses, so how would a neuron filter a signal as it was passing through it? As far as I know, it doesn't!

NOTE:
As noted by @WSYWYG, LTP and LTD are also important, they stand for Long Term Potentiation and Depression. These are names given to the long term increase or decrease in sensitivity of a synapse, that is a neuron can become more or less likely to pass on a signal over long periods of time due to the pattern or frequency of signals it receives. Googling the terms will lead you to a wealth of vastly more detailed information on these topics.

EDIT:
As an addendum, your body can inhibit neurons selectively, so as a wild stab in the dark, it may be interesting to see if *ignoring* a sensation from part of your body is the direct result of of external inhibiting (filtering) of signals incoming from ascending neural pathways... but don't trust me on that!

Comment: I can't imagine how would they lern it - the action potential is just chemical-a physical reaction, isn't it?

Comment: Learn? I don't believe I've used that word. I'm simply saying that a bunch of neurons can make simple calculations about whether or not they will pass on a signal that they receive.  A neuron might require 10units of neurotransmitter to fire, if it has 10 incoming connections that only release 1 unit each, it will ignore any incoming signals unless all 10 incoming signals fire at the same time OR one signal fires 10 times in quick succession.

Comment: you can also add a note on LTP and LTD

Comment: @Troyseph I think I still didn't get it. Do you think there is some natural mechanism that infiltrates known unimportant signals (then we had it from birth - wouldn't be affectable. Is it?)? I wouldn't really see much relations with LTP then, could you please explain to me? And am I understanding you right, that stray paths just won't get as much neurotransmitters? How is that?

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up on the meaning of the word "Important". The neuron triggers based ONLY on the neurotransmitter concentrations in its synapse (that it can detect). This concentration has to be above a threshold, if it isn't, then the signal is ignored. It could be said to have been unimportant. The note in my answer suggests that the threshold can be modified externally however that isn't totally relevant to the question.

Comment: @Troyseph is the answer on my question: "Is by filtering unimportant information meant more than gradual attenuation caused by long way up? "No?

Comment: @Probably I'm not sure anything in your last comment made sense...

Comment: @Probably after much re-reading of your comment, I've not mentioned anything about attenuation of signals, I've in no way suggested that an attenuated signal inside a neuron might get dropped as unimportant.

Comment: @Troyseph Oh, never mind, I think it makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
The thalamus is the most important neural station for the filtering of peripheral information to the cerebral cortex.

**Background**
Sleep is a prime example of where much, if not all, of the peripheral input ascending to the brain is filtered out. The **[thalamus](http://radiopaedia.org/articles/thalamus)** situated in the brain stem is the major gateway for the flow of information toward the [cerebral cortex](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rswenson/NeuroSci/chapter_11.html) and is the first station at which incoming signals can be blocked by synaptic inhibition. This mechanism contributes to the shift that the brain undergoes as it changes from an aroused state, open to signals from the outside world, to the closed state of sleep [(Steriade *et al*., 1993)](http://lions-talk-science.org/2015/01/21/paying-attention-why-you-want-to-have-a-filter/).

One way in which the thalamus does this is by generating slow-wave oscillations, so characteristic of the delta waves observed in slow-wave sleep. These slow waves are apparent in the cortical [electroencephalogram](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/eeg/basics/definition/prc-20014093) (EEG) as well as in the thalamus. The slow oscillations are generated by intrinsic oscillations, probably by thalamic cells, and effectively block incoming information to be shunted to the cortex through thalamo-cortical connections. A similar mechanism underlies sleep spindles, also associated with thalamic unresponsiveness to gate information to the cortex (Fig. 1). [(Steriade *et al*., 1993)](http://lions-talk-science.org/2015/01/21/paying-attention-why-you-want-to-have-a-filter/).

[image: spindles]
<sup>Sleep spindles generated in the thalamocortical network. (A) Shows sleep spindles in the EEG during sleep. (B) The trhalamocortical network, including the reticular thalamic nucleus (RTN) central to slow-wave sleep and sleep spindles. (C) single-cell recordings in the network. Source: [Steriade *et al*., 1993](http://lions-talk-science.org/2015/01/21/paying-attention-why-you-want-to-have-a-filter/)</sup>

Filtering of sensory information in the wake state is also performed by the RTN in the thalamus. [**Selective filtering**](http://lions-talk-science.org/2015/01/21/paying-attention-why-you-want-to-have-a-filter/) can occur through a top-down process. For example, when watching a movie, the cortex tells the **reticular nucleus** in the brain stem to filter other irrelevant input (other folks in the cinema, sounds of popcorn etc.).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Steriade *et al*., *Science* (1993); **262**: 679-84](http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/pmidlookup?view=long&pmid=8235588)</sub>

Comment: How does the sound of popcorn get filtered as unimportant when sounds in the movie don't?

Comment: @Troyseph - By active feedback from the cortex.